# converting Matlab code to python 3.5+

Tags: python, matlab, python-3.x, matplotlib, matlab-compiler

I find some difficulties with fscanf and to do a wavelet transform order 2 on python 3.5. As well, I want to verify if the plot block is right. 
Here is my Matlab code:

```
D_P=fopen('distance_profil.txt','r');
i=0;
  while(feof(D_P)==0)% test for end of file
    i=i+1;
    sign=fscanf(D_P,'%f , ');
    classe=fgetl(D_P);
    %Wavelet Transform
    [caH(i,:),cdH(i,:)] = dwt(sign,'db2');         
    %Segmentation    
    loc=[];
    [pks,locs] = findpeaks(abs(cdH(i,:)),'threshold',3);
    loc=[loc,locs];
    mod=abs(cdH(i,:));
    figure
    titre = ['distance profil : ' classe];

    subplot(2,1,1); plot(sign); title(titre); 
    hold on, plot(2*locs,sign(2*locs),'dr')
    subplot(2,1,2); plot(abs(cdH(i,:))); title('Module des Details coef. for db2');
    hold on, plot(locs,mod(locs),'dr')     
end
```

And below is my attempt with Python code

```
import pywt
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks_cwt
from scipy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

D_P= open ("distance_profil.txt","r")
i=0

while True:
    line = D_P.readline().strip()
    if line == '':

        def ReadFile():
            sign = []
            with open('textfiledata.txt', 'rt') as myFile:
                for line in myFile:
                    sign.append(map(int, line.split(',')))
            return sign

        classe = D_P.readline().rstrip()
        cA= np.array(sign)
        cD= np.array(sign)

        i+=1

        array[cA[i,], cD[i,]] = pywt.dwt([sign, 'db2'])

        loc = []
        [pks,locs] = find_peaks_cwt(abs(cdH([i,]),'threshold',3)

        loc = [loc,locs]
        mod=abs(cdH[i,])  

        plt.figure()
        plt.subplot(2,2,1)
        plt.plot(sign,2*locs,sign(2*locs),'ro')
        plt.title('distance profil : ' , classe)

        plt.subplot(2,2,2)
        plt.plot(abs(cdH(i,)),locs,mod(locs),'ro')
        plt.title("Module des Details coef. for db2")

        plt.show()

    break
```

Comment: So what about your attempt?

Comment: How should we know if your code is right? Please read [ask].

Comment: I have error for this instruction array[cA[i,], cD[i,]] = pywt.dwt([sign, 'db2'])

Comment: The matlab code is right because it was given from my professorand when I compile it , I get the right simulations. But for python code I have errors

Comment: I wanted to tell you to read [ask], I must have forgot. What makes you think that "I have errors" is sufficient information under any circumstances?

Comment: Honestly, this code has so many problems that I don't even know where to start....

Answer (score 4):

The two problems are that your Python code is not doing the same thing as your MATLAB code in a lot of places, and your Python code is invalid in multiple places.

First, in the MATLAB code, this line continues to loop until you reach the end of the file: `while(feof(D_P)==0)%`.  You apparently are trying to do the same thing with this line in python: `if line == '':`.  However, that runs the code only if the line is blank.

You can use this approach in python, but you shouldn't.  You can just loop over the lines as though they were an array, using `for line in D_P:`.  This will automatically loop over the lines of `D_P`, putting each line in variable `line`.  Also, you should use `with open ("distance_profil.txt","r") as D_P:` to safely open and close the file, as is done in the `ReadFile` function.  And you can use `enumerate` to keep track of the index with `for i, line in enumerate(D_P):`.  You also try to read each line twice, which means you really end up reading every other line.

The next problem is with this line `cA= np.array(sign)`.  You do not define the `sign` variable anywhere.  It is defined in the `ReadFile()` function, which you never use and should delete.  So instead of using the `sign` variable, it is instead using the `scipy.sign` function, which you would have overriden if you had defined the `sign` variable.  That is why `from ___ import *` is a bad idea.  Use `import scipy as sp` or something like that.  However, you don't need that since you only use one `scipy` function, which you import separately.

Unlike in MATLAB, functions are first-class objects in Python.  You can use them like any other variable.  So you are creating an array containing one function rather than the numeric data you apparently intend.  This fails, however, for the `dwt` function, which needs numeric input.  What you need to do is convert the line of text into an array of numbers.  The approach used in `ReadLine` is okay, except it is reading the wrong file and read the entire file instead of one line, did you copy that from somewhere?  However, it isn't a very good approach.  It is better to use `np.fromstring(line.strip(), sep=' ')`.  This will interpret a string as a sequence of numbers separated by spaces (replace with whatever you need) and convert it into a numpy array.  This is faster and easier.

Next, with the `dwt` function, you assign to `array[cA[i,], cD[i,]]`.  This isn't doing what you want and won't work because there is no `array` variable.  If `array` were a 2D numpy array, this would assign the results of `dwt` to the indexes at the coordinate corresponding to the value at index `i` of `cA` and `cD`.  You just want to assign to `cA` and `cD`.   That means you can also remove the earlier definitions of `cA` and `cD`.

Then, with the `dwt` call, you wrap the inputs in `[]`.  In Python this passes a list as a single argument rather than the two arguments you want.  In MATLAB it wouldn't work either, since it would try to concatenate a numeric array with a character array (which will fail) and will also pass that as a single input to the function.  So do `pywt.dwt(sign, 'db2')`.

So that line would be: `cA, cD = pywt.dwt(sign, 'db2')`.

Also, you use `cdH` several places, but never define it.  Is it supposed to be `cD`?  Also with `cdH([i,])`, MATLAB doesn't differentiate between function calls and array access, but python does.  You need to use square brackets `[]` and only square brackets for indexing.  `cdH([i,])` will be interpreted as "call the function `cdH` with the list input `[i,]`, which won't work because `cdH` isn't a function (or wouldn't be if it were defined).  The trailing comma is also redundant.  So you just do `cdh[i]`.

Next, you define `loc` as an empty list, then define `locs`, then do `loc = [loc, locs]`.  In MATLAB, this appends `locs` to `loc` (which is redundant, but valid).  In python, however, this creates a list that looks like `[[], locs]`, which is completely different.  You should just reduce those three lines to `[pks,loc] = find_peaks_cwt(abs(cdH([i,]),'threshold',3)`.

Also, below, you write `sign(2*locs)`.  As I said, you need to use brackets for indexing, so this needs to be `sign[2*locs]`.

Next, python doesn't have a `mod` function.  Use `%` to do modulus in Python.  I am not sure what the `mod` with a single argument does in your version of MATLAB, in mine it raises and error.  I assume from context, however, that you are trying to get the fractional part, which would be `locs%1`.

Finally, you do `plt.plot(abs(cdH(i,)),locs,mod(locs),'ro')`.  Neither MATLAB nor Python would know how to plot with three arrays like this.  You either need to split `plt.plot(abs(cdH(i,)))` into its own `plot` command like the MATLAB code does, or put `np.arange(len(cdH(i,)))` as the first argument to `plot`.  Same with the other plot.

Overall, it seems like you aren't very familiar with either MATLAB or Python (or both).  It would be worthwhile to brush up on the basics of both before trying to write code like those again.

Comment: It would also be prudent to [teach OP how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844641/converting-matlab-code-to-python-3-5#comment68907906_40844641).